# Calculating average speed as weighted mean

Tags: kinematics, velocity, speed

In the books it says that average speed is just s/t. But I am wondering if we can calculate average speed using weighted average mean, using time or using length of path? For instance, if we know that one drove 1/3 with speed v1 an 2/3 with speed v2, can we find:

v<sub>average</sub> = v<sub>1</sub>*1/3 + v<sub>2</sub>*2/3?

Or the same using time component if we know it.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{t_2-t_1} \int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2} dt \, v(t) =\frac{1}{t_2-t_1}\int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2} dt \, \frac{ds(t)}{dt} =\frac{s(t_2)-s(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}$

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, displacement/time is the average *velocity*, not the average speed. Consider a particle that starts and ends its motion at the same place. Then its average *velocity* is zero, but its average *speed* (where speed is the absolute value of velocity) is greater than zero.

Displacement/time is the average velocity with respect to time. This is not necessarily the same as the average velocity with respect to distance. To see the difference, consider a particle that travels at $4$ m/s for a distance of $6$ metres and then at $12$ m/s for a distance of $6$ metres. It has travelled $12$ metres in $2$ seconds so its average velocity with respect to time is $6$ m/s, but its average velocity with respect to distance is $8$ m/s.